# query filter on postgresql array column using array.contains()

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an array column (required of me, I know this is not typical convention) that I need to filter on in a query. I am trying to use contains(),

```
  db.session.query(table).filter((table.name.ilike
    ('%'+name+'%')),
    table.languages.contains(language)).limit(200)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
    NotImplementedError: ARRAY.contains() not implemented for the base 
    ARRAY 
    type; please use the dialect-specific ARRAY type
```

I am new to Flask-Sqlalchemy so I am not sure how to use this correctly. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the type of language?

Comment: @mad_ python accessing postgresql db using flask-sqlalchemy

Comment: I was asking about the argument `language`

Answer (score 1):

This Expection means you should use `dialect-specific ARRAY type` to instead the base ARRAY type. So in your models definition, Use `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY` to instead `ARRAY`

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
class table(db.Model):
    ...
    languages = db.Column(ARRAY) # notice this ARRAY import from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql
```

Now, you can use `db.session.query(table).filter(table.languages.contains([language])).limit(200)`.

Comment: And this answers the original question how?

Comment: Yes, I have the same problem and use it fix out.

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details

Comment: @gehbiszumeis Thank you. This is my first answer. I will re-edit it soon.